# MVC3 Authentication with SSRS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, authentication, forms-authentication

i have created an mvc3 web application that uses forms based authentication. one part of the site has links to microsoft ssrs reporting services reports and these reports are launched in an iframe from one of the views.

the problem i am having is that when a user log's into the main site and then subsequently clicks on one of the reporting links, they receive a windows modal login box.

i would like to stop them from receiving this authentication step and rely on the forms based authentication they already went through. at the same time i want to prevent non-authenticated users from typing in one of the ssrs report links into their browser and viewing them without having logged in..

can this be achieved using forms based authentication alone?

thanks
grant.

Comment: Since SSRS sits in an IIS application, is this not the same problem as getting a single forms login to authenticate multiple applications?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up SSRS with forms authentication? If not then if you configure forms authentication on SSRS then you can share forms authentication across multiple applications.

I can't describe step for step how you would do this but hopefully the following links will help:

[Authentication in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152899%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)